# Upload React app to Netlify and received a 401

Tags: reactjs, github, netlify, http-status-code-401

Here is link to my netlify shop - https://find-my-rescue.netlify.app/

This is my GitHub link - https://github.com/mrshawnhum/capstone-starter-mrshawnhum

When i run a Yarn Start inside my VS code, everything is loaded and running. Yet i deployed to Netlify and i received this message about my api.

**{"type":"https://httpstatus.es/401", "status":401, "title":"Unauthorized", "detail":"Access token invalid or expired"}**

It shouldn't be my access token because i used petfinder-sdk from github to generate my token key when i give it a api key and secret key.

Comment: Can you check again environment variables to make sure `REACT_APP_API_KEY` and `REACT_APP_SECRET_KEY` is correct?

Comment: Yes, everything is correct on the keys